# Promise all behaviour?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Below is the simple code of Promise.all, But the output is confusing the behaviour of Promise.all.

```
// A simple promise that resolves after a given time
const timeOut = (t) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Completed in ${t}`)
    }, t)
  })
}

// Resolving a normal promise.
timeOut(1000)
 .then(result => console.log(result)) // Completed in 1000

// Promise.all
Promise.all([timeOut(1000), timeOut(2000), timeOut(2000)])
 .then(result => console.log(result))
```

**Can some one explain me why the output is not:**

```
Completed in 1000
Completed in 2000
Completed in 2000
['Completed in 1000', 'Completed in 2000', 'Completed in 2000']
```

**This is the output I'm getting:**

```
Completed in 1000
['Completed in 1000', 'Completed in 2000', 'Completed in 2000']
```

Comment: I believe that the internal log statements are not being called due to optimization of the `Promise.all` call. Each of the promise's `then()` functions is not being called.

Comment: *"The Promise.all() static method takes an iterable of promises as input and returns a single Promise. This returned promise fulfills when all of the input's promises fulfill (including when an empty iterable is passed), with an array of the fulfillment values. It rejects when any of the input's promises rejects, with this first rejection reason."* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) documentation FTW!

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl What "internal log statements" are you talking about?

Comment: You have only two `console.log()` statements in your code, each of which is getting executed once. Why would you expect 4 lines of output?

Comment: Maybe a way to think about this is to remove the line of code you have commented as "// Resolving a normal promise."  WIth that gone, what should you expect to see from the Promise.all, then log?  Just the array, right?  Okay, put the "normal promise" line back in.  Now, does it meet expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The Promise.all() static method takes an iterable of promises as input
> and returns a single Promise. This returned promise fulfills when all
> of the input's promises fulfill (including when an empty iterable is
> passed), **with an array of the fulfillment values.** It rejects when any
> of the input's promises rejects, with this first rejection reason.

So you get one **single** promise, whose value is an array of the originally passed (now resolved) promises.

You added a `.then()` only on one promise:

```js
// Resolving a normal promise.
timeOut(1000)
 .then(result => console.log(result)) // Completed in 1000
```

Hence, the appropriate message was printed.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the promises and call their `then()` resolution handlers.

```js
// A simple promise that resolves after a given time
const timeOut = (t) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Completed in ${t}`)
    }, t)
  })
}

// Resolving a normal promise.
timeOut(1000)
 .then(result => console.log(result)) // Completed in 1000

// Promise.all
Promise
  .all([timeOut(1000), timeOut(2000), timeOut(2000)]
    .map(p => p.then(msg => {
      console.log(msg) // map and call `then()` which receives the message
      return msg // make sure you return the original message
    })))
 .then(result => console.log(result))
```